# Problems Deploying a Node.js app on Heroku Using MongoLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, mlab

I'm attempting to deploy a very simple app to Heroku.  The code for the application can be found on Ray Wenderlich's site, here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/61078/write-simple-node-jsmongodb-web-service-ios-app  I keep getting the same error whenever I try to have Heroku compile the code...

```
var mongoHost = "mongodb://username:password@ds041140.mongolab.com:41140/heroku_app23491233";
var mongoPort = 41140; 
var collectionDriver;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort)); //B
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) { //C
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1); //D
  }
  var db = mongoClient.db("heroku_app23491233");  // E
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db); //F
});
```

When I type `heroku logs`, the error I get comes from `if (!mongoClient)` above...

```
app[web.1]: Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first
```

I'm sure the problem lies somewhere in my attempt to connect to the MongoLab database.  I've copied the URI from MongoLab and I've created a user with the proper credentials.

I can connect to localhost just fine with very similar code, so I'm not sure what is going wrong in this example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/index.html), my best guess is that it's because the `Server` constructor expects the first argument to contain only the host name (in the case of your MongoLab, `ds041140.mongolab.com`). However, I think you can pass your connection string into `MongoClient.connect`:

```
// Make sure to replace username and password with the proper values.
var mongoHost = "mongodb://username:password@ds041140.mongolab.com:41140/heroku_app23491233";

MongoClient.connect(mongoHost, function(err, db) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    db.collection('mongoclient_test').update({a:1}, {b:1}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
        db.close();

        if (err) return console.log(err);

        console.log('Okay', result);
    });
});
```

[Documentation Page For MongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect)

Hopefully that helps!